# Measuring throughput in cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

This may sound as an elementary question - but I am confused with all the literature.
I have a 3-node cassandra cluster on 3.11.x,with 1 seed node.
We are testing brute force write throughput in this setup with a single threaded client seated outside the cluster.
With nodetool and cqsl at my disposal - how do I go about realistically assessing the following:

```
How much volume was processed by each node.
How much of the total time was consumed 
a)by the actual flush + compaction at each node 
b)time taken by the cluster to resolve the node/partition(hashing)
c)network latency in chaperoning the data to the node
```

Comment: why does (a) matter? its asynchronous to the requests and done in batch periodically. for (b) its in nanoseconds likely dependent on data (murmur3 of the partition key). (c) ping x 2 will probably be close enough but there are Messaging metrics

Comment: Understood - how do we accurately measure volume at each node ,and whether a node has become a hotspot

Comment: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsTablehisto.html helps you finding hotspots

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be monitoring JMX port of Cassandra by a tool like Opennms or Zabbix and compare Metrics such as Mutation, compatcion, etc (Hundreds of Metrics there):
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsMonitoring.html